# Is the chrome devtools API allowed in the store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

This is my first time developing for Chrome. My question is: if i use devtools so i can create panels, will my extension pass through to the store or is it only for developers to test stuff with? So basically is it legal in the store extensions to use devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.devtools.panels` is listed as under [Stable APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). Any APIs listed as stable are perfectly ok to publish in the Chrome Web Store. Keep in mind that you should provide enough of a description and getting started guide that people understand what the extension does and how it works.